# Understanding a particular automorphism of general linear group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I am trying to understand the following automorphism of general linear group in terms of matrices.

(0) Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $k$.

(1) Given $u\in {\rm GL}(V)$, let $\check{u}$ denote contragradient of $u$.

(2) Let $t:V\rightarrow V^*$ denote a correlation map onto dual space.

Then the map 
$u\mapsto t^{-1}\check{u}t$ is an automorphism of ${\rm GL}(V)$.

**Q.1** If we consider ${\rm GL}_n(k)$ instead of ${\rm GL}(V)$, how this map is intrepreted? I didn't understand properly the maps in (2).

**Q.2** The map in (1) in terms of matrices is transpose map, am I right?

---

The automorphism mentioned above appears on first page of the paper *A new type of automorphism of general linear group over a ring* by Reiner I. ([this link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969903))

Comment: From a google search, it appears that the matrix for the contragradient is the transpose of the *inverse*. I can't seem to find a reasonable definition of  the "correlation" map except in the context of a bilinear form --- are you talking about correlation for the standard inner product on $k^n$?

Comment: I am following a paper "A new type of automorphism of general linear group over a ring" by I. Reiner. The mentioned things before Q.1 are in front page of the paper.

Comment: OK, that's fine. But I'm *not* following that paper, and if you want my help, you're going to have to give more details. At the very least, a link might be nice...

Comment: Ah... you need to read more carefully: it says that $t$ is **a** correlation mapping $V$ to its dual, not **the** correlation. Perhaps to save us time, you might mention what reference 7 in the paper is (or even link to it), since that's apparently where we (and you) can learn more about such correlation maps.

Comment: OK; thanks for the help, suggestion and noticing error; I will do it as you said.